# Onde criar uma base de dados sem ter previlégios

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Criei, no emprego, um "programa" em Access pois necessito de uma base de dados, e ter um ambiente gráfico, tudo estava a correr em até que a empresa "lembrou-se" de eliminar o Access do pacote disponível. Como não sou administrador do sistema, venho perguntar se existe alguma alternativa de criar um programa que tenha base de dados para utilizar no emprego, pode até ter de ser criado em casa mas tenho de poder usa-lo sem instalar no pc do emprego.

Comment: Tentou o sql lite?

Comment: Com o SQL lite é possivel criar um ambiente gráfico ?

Comment: Não, ele é só o banco.

Comment: Exato, eu necessito algo tipo o Access, com BD e ambiente gráfico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Microsoft Excel**.

Nele você também pode criar formulários, programar em VBA e persistir no modelo Access, usando SQL, sem dependência de outros softwares. Não tem os "wizards" do Access, então exige mais trabalho para chegar aos mesmos resultados.

Lembre-se que, enquanto o aplicativo **Microsoft Access** é uma solução completa, a base de dados na verdade é apenas um arquivo em disco que pode ser gerado ou acessado por qualquer outro aplicativo em qualquer linguagem onde o **driver** estiver disponível.

Ou seja: os dados que você persistia usando o Microsoft Access podem ser lidos e alterados também por Java, Delphi, C#... e até por um script VBS (Excel é apenas uma das possibilidades).

Answer (score 1):

Se você está interessado em fazer uma GUI simples, existe varias opções:
c9.io,
nitrous.io
firebase
heroku

são todas plataformas online onde você pode desenvolver algo e ter acesso ao banco de dados que eles oferecem junto.

ou mesmo o google drive e o dropbox.